# SVG to image quality reducing

Tags: java, image, svg, jpeg, batik

My requirement is to convert .SVG to image. The SVG files are generated by internal tool. I am trying these by 2 approaches:

1. Converting SVG to image using JPEG transcoder. My SVG files are complex maps, that has some text on it. The resulting image's quality has reduced a lot the text is not readable lloks blured.
2. Converting SVG to PDF and PDF to image. I am performing SVG to PDF using Batik and PDF to image using PDFRenderer. 
   PDF to image produces a image that is not readable.

Comment: Why JPEG?  For sharp lines, I would use PNG.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your reply! I used the code provided in the developer site, I tried with png, but it is producing same result. Is there an alternate api that I can use apart from Transcoder.?

Comment: Don't know.  Will cede that to anyone..

Answer (score 0):

Try [svgexport](https://github.com/shakiba/svgexport), it takes a quality parameter and can export to png, jpeg and pdf.  I'm its author.